# Is there a way to created nested Drawers in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, material-design

Been trying out Flutter and looking at ways to show a user the current navigation stack, as well as allowing them to quickly jump to any point within the current stack.

My current approach to that is to display a series of nested Drawers.

So a use case might be, the initial Drawer displays a list of continents, user taps on Europe, another Drawers slides out from underneath the continent Drawer to show a list of countries, then maybe another Drawer after that showing states/provinces, etc.

So it should look something similar to this:
[image]

I'm currently stuck at figuring out how to implement this using Drawers. Is Drawers even the best approach to this? Possibly managing a Row with Drawers as children?

Or maybe I should consider rolling my own implementation via controlling how a bunch of interactable ListViews appear, or something along those lines.

Comment: You should be fully customized for this. Load the view with translation animation and so on. No standard way handles this...

Comment: Hey @kronon wondering what you did here running into a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's actually possible, and that might not look nice in a UI.

Flutter [`Drawer`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Drawer-class.html) documentation says:

> Drawers are typically used with the Scaffold.drawer property.

And the [`Scaffold.drawer`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scaffold/drawer.html) property accepts only 1 [`Widget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Widget-class.html):

> drawer → **Widget**
>
> A panel displayed to the side of the body, often hidden on mobile devices. Swipes in from either left-to-right (TextDirection.ltr) or right-to-left (TextDirection.rtl) [...]
>      final

Meaning you can only use 1 `Drawer` in that property. And the `Drawer` class doesn't have a drawer property.

Probably, using [`ExpansionPanel`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ExpansionPanel-class.html) and [`ExpansionPanelList`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ExpansionPanelList-class.html) will allow you to collapse and expand the rest of the options. Getting you closer to the functionality you want.

There is also an [expandable 2.1.1](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/expandable) plugin that says:

> `Expandable` should not be confused with `ExpansionPanel`. `ExpansionPanel`, which is a part of Flutter material library, is designed to work only within `ExpansionPanelList` and cannot be used for making other widgets, for example, expandable Card widgets.

Giving you more freedom to use different `Widgets`s.